# How can I print array in parallel using php

Tags: php

i have one table which name is `images`, in which 2 columns: `user_id` & `image_path`, values of `user_id` => `1,1,2,2,3`, values of `image_path` => `abc,xyz,qwe,asd,wes`

in other words (i need following output using php):

```
user_id:1
image_path:abc
           xyz

user_id:2
image_path:qwe
           asd

user_id:3
image_path:wes
```

Code is:

```
$sqlb="SELECT * FROM image"; 
$resultb=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlb); 
if($resultb->num_rows>0) { $
    i=0; 
    while($rowb=$resultb->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $user_id[$i]['user_id']=$rowb['user_id']; 
        $user_id[$i]['image_path']=array($rowb['image_path']); 
        $i++; 
    } 
    $response['session']=TRUE; 
    $response['session_status']=TRUE; 
    $response['Msg']="successfully users data find";
    $response['user_detail']=$user_id; 
    echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: when user upload image then data save with user_id and image path into database column 'image' i want to print data in above form using php code

Comment: ok, so what is your problem ?

Comment: i need code in php

Comment: Did you try anything ? if yes share with us ?

Comment: i am using this "select all from image" and data fetch using while loop but problem is that my output like this                                                                   user_id 1 image_path abc                                                                              user_id 1 image_path xyz ......same as it is for all, i want to userid print only 1 time.

Comment: Ohh dear, You just got `-3` and about to close this question, just because you didn't provid all info, like `what you tried`, `what is current output` and `what is expected` clearly

Comment: Either you need to do `group by` or change in `php code` to make a group of `user_id`, please don't ask to answer.

Comment: $sqlb="SELECT * FROM `image`";
$resultb=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlb);
if($resultb->num_rows>0)
 {
   $i=0;
  while($rowb=$resultb->fetch_assoc())
{ 
 $user_id[$i]['user_id']=$rowb['user_id'];
 $user_id[$i]['image_path']=array($rowb['image_path']);
$i++;
}
$response['session']=TRUE;
$response['session_status']=TRUE;
$response['Msg']="successfully users data find";
$response['user_detail']=$user_id;
echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: Bhai, All the code should be in your question not in comment, so update your question what I said in above comment. May be this question is down-voted but next question will be up-voted, Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your result an associative array keyed by user ID. Then it's easy to collect all the image paths for the same user ID.

```
$result = array();
while ($rowb = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userid = $rowb['user_id'];
    if (!isset($result[$userid])) {
        $result[$userid] = array('user_id' => $userid, 'image_path' => array());
    }
    $result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $rowb['image_path'];
}
```

The resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
    "1": { "user_id": 1, "image_path": ["abc", "xyz"]},
    "2": { "user_id": 2, "image_path": ["qwe", "asd"]},
    "3": { "user_id": 3, "image_path": ["wes"]}
}
```

Comment: Very THANKS because previuos 20 days i was in trouble